# Switching Integral and Sum in the Integral of $\sin(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the antiderivative of $\sin(x)$ using it's Maclaurin series:
\begin{align*}
\int \sin(x) dx &= \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int x^{2n+1}dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int x^{2n+1}dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!} +c \\
&= \frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}-\cdots+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c \\
&= -\cos(x)-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c
\end{align*}

But I'm unsure on how to prove the switching of the Integrals.

Also, how does one make sense of the constant of integration still being inside the sum?

Comment: It doesn't make sense as an indefinite integral.

Comment: What you can do in the case of absolute convergence (as here) : Summing up the antiderivates of the terms of the Maclaurin series (without a constant) and add a constant at the end.

Comment: It is not a single constant of integration here. Each antiderivative has its own constant of integration, so $c_n$ not $c$. (Note that your sum converges if and only if $c=0$.) In order to obtain a sensible result, the series must converge (and can be written as just $C$). I prefer to note that from the Mean Value Theorem, $f'=g'$ if and only if $f=g+C$ for some constant $C$. From the Fundamental Theorem, clearly $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx} \int\sin(x)\,dx=\sin(x)$ and the derivative of the series for $-\cos(x)$ is $\sin(x)$, so these two functions only differ by an overall additive constant.

Comment: As for how to justify switching the sum and integral, that requires some notion of convergence. Power series converge uniformly on the interior of their interval of convergence, and uniform convergence allows for the interchange of sum and integral.

Comment: Not sure if helpful, but technically, you shouldn't have one single constant of integration. You should label them $c_n$ since they correspond to distinct integrals.

Comment: @CameronWilliams He could have something like $c_n=1/n^2$ which still would converge.

Comment: @SimonSMN You and I are in agreement.